# There's a 16px gap at the bottom of my webpage and.. a smiley face?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

There's a gap at the bottom of my webpage and for the life of me can't find what's causing it, there's also a smiley face?

Link to my site [here](http://lartmagazine.co.uk/)

Comment: HAXX! no, seriously, my bet is that you have conflicting character encodings somewhere, either in your source files, header meta tags or DB content.

Comment: And you want us to go visit your site to get pwned by whatever's got you? Doesn't sound like a good idea to me. You can certainly start finding it by disabling/stepping through JavaScript, and using dev tools to identify the markup. Then if you still need help, post the offending bit and a SSCCE.

Comment: Google: *stats.wordpress.com smiley face*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks something about a web site linking to the site. If the site dies, the question withers.

Answer (score 3):

Delete this from ur web page :-

```
<img id="wpstats" src="http://stats.wordpress.com/g.gif?host=lartmagazine.co.uk&amp;rand=0.734064391348511&amp;v=ext&amp;j=1%3A2.6.1&amp;blog=61388823&amp;post=0&amp;tz=0&amp;ref=http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/20702298/theres-a-16px-gap-at-the-bottom-of-my-webpage-and-a-smiley-face" alt="">
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find that on my webpage?

Comment: Then check if you can find wordpress plugin & delete it : <script src="http://stats.wordpress.com/e-201351.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it either?

Comment: For fast solution add this StyleSheet - `#wpstats{display: none;}`

Comment: I added that, the smiley face is gone but the gap is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Many WordPress themes have it in the `footer.php` file, it's stats stuff. 
You can safely remove it.

```
<img id="wpstats" src="http://stats.wordpress.com/g.gif?host=lartmagazine.co.uk&amp;rand=0.9615265580359846&amp;v=ext&amp;j=1%3A2.6.1&amp;blog=61388823&amp;post=0&amp;tz=0&amp;ref=http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/20702298/theres-a-16px-gap-at-the-bottom-of-my-webpage-and-a-smiley-face" alt="">
```